# Keyboard Font for LaTeX

Tags: fonts, keyboard

I'm currently writing a user guide containing a lot of keyboard shortcuts. I'm looking for a "keyboard" font where single characters or special keys (like <kbd>tab</kbd> or <kbd>backspace</kbd>) appear like the "real" key (i.e. with a box around; hope you get the idea).

Is there any package available for this or do I have to wrap one of the existing PS/TTF Fonts?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

The [keystroke](http://ctan.org/pkg/keystroke) package is your friend.

---

**Update:**

[Sadeq's suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5226/keyboard-font-for-latex/11197#11197) could be mimicked very inexpensively by the [pgf/tikZ](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) package.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\newcommand*\keystroke[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(key.base)]
    \node[%
      draw,
      fill=white,
      drop shadow={shadow xshift=0.25ex,shadow yshift=-0.25ex,fill=black,opacity=0.75},
      rectangle,
      rounded corners=2pt,
      inner sep=1pt,
      line width=0.5pt,
      font=\scriptsize\sffamily
    ](key) {#1\strut}
  ;
}

\begin{document}
  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
  \keystroke{Strg} The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
  \keystroke{Ctrl} The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
  \keystroke{Page $\uparrow$} \keystroke{Esc} \keystroke{F1}
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Comment: Excellent! So no one will really have to buy a font :) You saved us $120!

Comment: It was a great starting point. Now I am using following code (works correctly w/ sequences like Ctrl+F1): `\renewcommand*\keystroke[1]{\hspace{0.2ex}\tikz[baseline=(key.base)]\node[draw,text height=1.5ex,text depth=0ex,fill=black!10,drop shadow={shadow xshift=0.2ex,shadow yshift=-0.2ex,fill=black,opacity=0.50},rectangle,rounded corners=2pt,inner sep=2.75pt,line width=0.5pt,font=\footnotesize\sffamily] (key) {#1};\hspace{0.4ex}}`. `\re...`, because I still use keystroke package for convenient `\PgUp` and similar macros (you have to add `\ ` after them if used in the middle of sentence, etc.).

Comment: @Thorsten Donig Is there a way to make the box have a minimum width equal to the height? (So if I'm doing the . key it isn't just a tall thin box that looks no good). Thanks

Comment: @captainjamie: you can use the `minimum width` key inside the definition of `keystroke`.  `minimum width=1.2em` works for me.

Comment: This is especially helpful for alphabets such as Greek where I can use:
     \keystroke{῏} and   \keystroke{Ξ}, which might not be in a standard keystroke font.

Answer (score 104):

You can use the [`menukeys`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/menukeys) package which is included in `texlive-full`.

### Example

```
\documentclass[a5paper,9pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{menukeys}

\begin{document}
 \section{The Manual}
    You can visualize paths \directory{/home/moose/Desktop/manual.tex}
    or menus \menu{View > Highlight Mode > Markup > LaTeX} or key
    press combinations: \keys{\ctrl + \shift + F} is for formatting
    in Eclipse.

    You can also visualize \keys{\tab}, \keys{\capslock}, \keys{\Space}, 
    \keys{\arrowkeyup} and many more.
\end{document}
```

### Rendered

[image]

`menukeys` is included in `texlive-full`.

Comment: `\keys{\Alt}` returns a Mac-styled icon. How can I change this to something one would see in other types of keyboard?

Comment: Answering myself. Change Mac-style icons to Windows by running `\usepackage[os=win]{menukeys}`. Got it from http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/236889/12065.

Comment: Info for MikTex ppl: this package needs some other packages as dependencies and it might collide with other packages. For me it collided with \hypersetup options

Answer (score 32):

Another free keyboard font is Linux Biolinum Keyboard. See the following graphic for an example:

[image: Linux Biolinum Keyboard Sample]

Comment: Yes, and linux libertine. They're nicer than `keystroke`.

Comment: Very nice. But only available with the Libertine font.

Comment: Seems to have issues with horizontal alignment, though. I sort of like it, but it messes up the otherwise nice typesetting.

Answer (score 24):

the ones with Libertine:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{libertinekey}

\begin{document}

\LKeyStrg\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. \\
\LKeyStrg\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. \\
\LKeyPos\ \LKeyEsc \LKeyF{1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This package seems to have been depreciated. Will you please update the answer with the latest version (I think is libertineOTF).

Comment: why should it be deprecated? The above is an example for `pdflatex` and not `xetex` or `luatex`!

Comment: Look into `libertinekey.sty` (in an up-to-date distribution). It is unfortunately needed to load `libertine.sty` from `libertine-legacy`.

Comment: I see, but that seems to be a bug. All packages of `libertine-legacy` should be the old one. I'll report it.

Answer (score 14):

[Thorsten Donig's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5226/5227#5227) is excellent, and provides a free solution. However, if you are in need of a more advanced typographic solution, you may consider buying fonts specially designed to represent "keyboard caps."

One such font is the family of [PIXymbols Shadowkey](http://www.fonts.com/findfonts/detail.htm?productid=457047) fonts. In my opinion, they are prettier (but much more expensive!)

[image]

Comment: Or use an open-source such font, like Linux Biolinum.

Comment: @Raphink: See Philipp's answer!

Answer (score 10):

As an addition to [Thorsten Donig's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5227/115883) I modified his `\keystroke` command to get a similar 3D style as in the [keystroke package](http://ctan.org/pkg/keystroke), which he suggested.

---

[image]

---

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand*\keystroke[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(key.base), very thin, line cap=round, black, rounded corners=0pt]%
    \node [draw, fill=white, fill opacity=1, rectangle, rounded corners=2pt, inner sep=1pt, minimum width=1.2em, font=\scriptsize\sffamily] (key) {#1\strut};

    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
      \draw [rounded corners=1pt, fill=white] ($ (key.north west) + (-2pt, 2pt) $) rectangle ($ (key.south east) + (2pt, -2pt) $);

      \fill [gray!60] ($ (key.south west) + (2pt, 0.1pt) $) -- ($ (key.south west) + (-1pt, -2pt) $)
                  -- ($ (key.south east) + (1pt, -2pt) $)  -- ($ (key.south east) + (-2pt, 0.1pt) $) -- cycle;

      \fill [gray!60] ($ (key.south east) + (-0.1pt, 2pt) $) -- ($ (key.south east) + (2pt, -1pt) $)
                  -- ($ (key.north east) + (2pt, 1pt) $)    -- ($ (key.north east) + (-0.1pt, -2pt) $) -- cycle;
    \end{scope}

    \draw ($ (key.north west) + (0.1pt, -2pt) $) -- ($ (key.north west) + (-2pt, 1pt) $);
    \draw ($ (key.north west) + (2pt, -0.1pt) $) -- ($ (key.north west) + (-1pt, 2pt) $);

    \draw ($ (key.north east) + (-0.1pt, -2pt) $) -- ($ (key.north east) + (2pt, 1pt) $);
    \draw ($ (key.north east) + (-2pt, -0.1pt) $) -- ($ (key.north east) + (1pt, 2pt) $);

    \draw ($ (key.south west) + (0.1pt, 2pt) $) -- ($ (key.south west) + (-2pt, -1pt) $);
    \draw ($ (key.south west) + (2pt, 0.1pt) $) -- ($ (key.south west) + (-1pt, -2pt) $);

    \draw ($ (key.south east) + (-0.1pt, 2pt) $) -- ($ (key.south east) + (2pt, -1pt) $);
    \draw ($ (key.south east) + (-2pt, 0.1pt) $) -- ($ (key.south east) + (1pt, -2pt) $);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
  \keystroke{Strg} The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
  \keystroke{Ctrl} The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
  \keystroke{Page $\uparrow$} \keystroke{Esc} \keystroke{F1}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

As a supplement to Philipp's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11216/9077), I'm providing a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) for the Linux Biolinum Keyboard font. You need to compile with `xelatex` or `lualatex`. The macros are given in the [`libertine`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/libertine) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/libertine/doc/libertine.pdf).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\begin{document}

First hit this key sequence:\LKeyShiftX{H}

Then hit these keys one by one:
\LKey{E}\LKey{L}\LKey{L}\LKey{O}\LKeySpace\LKey{W}\LKey{O}\LKey{R}\LKey{L}\LKey{D}

And finally hit the \LKeyEnter\ key.

You should now see the phrase ``Hello world'' on your screen.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

[Arkandis](http://arkandis.tuxfamily.org/adffonts.html) also provides 2 keyboard fonts, suitable for, I think, French keyboards. These can be used directly with Xe/LuaTeX.

[image: KeyboardADF]

[image: KeyboradADFNo2]

Code is a hacked version of [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23866/):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}% ref. egreg's answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23866/
\usepackage[landscape,textwidth=239mm,textheight=480pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec,setspace}
\newfontface\keyone{KeypadADF.otf}
\newfontface\keytwo{KeypadADFNo2.otf}
\newcount\charcount
\parindent=0pt
\doublespacing
\begin{document}

  \keyone
  \chardef\highest=\XeTeXcountglyphs\font
  \offinterlineskip
  \loop
  \makebox[35mm][l]{\strut\vrule\,{\normalfont\number\charcount}\hfill \XeTeXglyph\charcount}\hskip1mm plus 1mm
  \ifnum\charcount<\numexpr\highest-1\relax
  \advance\charcount1
  \repeat
  \newpage

  \keytwo
  \charcount=0
  \chardef\highest=\XeTeXcountglyphs\font
  \offinterlineskip
  \loop
  \makebox[35mm][l]{\strut\vrule\,{\normalfont\number\charcount}\hfill \XeTeXglyph\charcount}\hskip1mm plus 1mm
  \ifnum\charcount<\numexpr\highest-1\relax
  \advance\charcount1
  \repeat

\end{document}
```