# How to create a keybutton in latex?

Tags: boxes, text-decorations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keyboard Font for LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5226/keyboard-font-for-latex)

So the result looks like:

> Press <kbd>F5</kbd> for help.

I've checked the fancybox package, but it only includes three patterns: doublebox, ovalbox, shadowbox. I need something like buttonbox.

Comment: See: [How to look up a symbol](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol). In this case, the symbol list shows that you may use the `keystroke` package: Press `\keystroke{F5}` for help.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a short tikz command can help you to do it

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\tikzstyle{buttonstyle} = [rectangle, fill = black!30, draw = black!80, drop shadow, font={\sffamily\bfseries}, text=white]

\newcommand*{\button}[1]{\tikz{\node[buttonstyle] {#1};}}

\begin{document}
Press \button{F5} for help !
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is also possible to get it with `pdflatex`. I used `xelatex` (`lualatex`) in this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertineotf}

\begin{document}
Press \LKeyF{5} for help !
\end{document}
```

[image]

for a newer system, like TL2014 runt this document with `xelatex` or `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}

\begin{document}
Press \LKey{5} for help !
\end{document}
```

Comment: Didn't work for me in TeXLive 2014: `Undefined control sequence`

Comment: see my edited answer

Answer (score 2):

Improving a little on **Ger**'s answer:

### Code

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\newcommand{\button}[1]%
{   \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(tempname.base)]
        \node[draw=gray, fill=yellow!5, rounded corners=0.5pt, inner sep=2pt, minimum width=1.5em, minimum height=1.5em, general shadow={fill=gray!50, shadow xshift=0.5pt, shadow yshift=-0.5pt, shadow scale=1.15}] (tempname) {#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\textsc{Count von Count:} There are \button{8}, \button{8} buttons!

\end{document}
```

### Result

[image]