# Best way to use Linux Biolinum Keyboard with fontspec?

Tags: xetex, luatex, fontspec, libertine, keyboard

I am trying to typeset keyboard shortcuts in my document, e.g. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>. The Linux Libertine font family includes a nice [keyboard font](http://www.linuxlibertine.org/index.php?id=86&L=1#c586) that I would like to use. What's the best way to use it with fontspec? I tried the following and while it works, my latex-foo isn't that great and I was wondering if there is a better way. I also tried to use `\char"XXXX` instead of using the unicode character directly, but that didn't work.

```
\newfontface{\keyboardfont}{Linux Biolinum Keyboard O}
\newcommand{\key}[1]{{\keyboardfont #1}}
\newcommand{\ctrl}{\key{}}
\newcommand{\shift}{\key{}}
\newcommand{\alt}{\key{}}
% etc.
```

This allows you to typeset "normal" keys by using the `\key` macro, but special keys all have to be set up individually. For example, you can type:

```
\ctrl+\shift+\key{S}
```

which results in:

[image]

Is there a way to define a "smart" `\key` command that understands special keys? So that the above can be typed like this?

```
\key{ctrl}+\key{shift}+\key{S}
```

A similar question that unfortunately doesn't provide an answer for fontspec: [Keyboard Font for LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5226/keyboard-font-for-latex)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following proposal is probably not the best solution. The package [`libertineotf`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/libertineotf) offers a lot of keys accessible via commands `\LKey<name>` like `\LKeyEnter` and a command `\LKey{<glyph name>}`. This can be used to define a command that nearly does what you want (using `etoolbox`' `\ifcsdef` and `\csuse`):

```
\newcommand{\key}[1]{%
  \ifcsdef{LKey#1}
    {\csuse{LKey#1}}
    {\LKey{#1}}%
  }
```

The biggest drawback is that for some keys only the German commands exist (e.g. there is `\LKeyStrg` but no `\LKeyCtrl`) so we need to do some extra work:

```
\newcommand*\LKeyCtrl{\LKey{C_t_r_l}}
\newcommand*\LKeySpace{\LKey{uniE18C}}

% let German names to English ones:
\let\LKeyStrg\LKeyCtrl
\let\LKeyEntf\LKeyDel

% add Gnglish equivalents of combinations
\let\LKeyCtrlX\LKeyStrgX
\let\LKeyShiftCtrlX\LKeyShiftStrgX
\let\LKeyCtrlAltX\LKeyStrgAltX
\let\LKeyCtrlAltDel\LKeyReset
```

With these definitions you can use `\key` like this:

```
\key{Ctrl}+\key{Shift}+\key{S}
\key{Enter} \key{Alt} \key{F}{12}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertineotf}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% for \ifcsdef, \csuse
% add not directly accessible macros:
\newcommand*\LKeyCtrl{\LKey{C_t_r_l}}
\newcommand*\LKeySpace{\LKey{uniE18C}}

% let German names to English ones:
\let\LKeyStrg\LKeyCtrl
\let\LKeyEntf\LKeyDel

% add Gnglish equivalents of combinations
\let\LKeyCtrlX\LKeyStrgX
\let\LKeyShiftCtrlX\LKeyShiftStrgX
\let\LKeyCtrlAltX\LKeyStrgAltX
\let\LKeyCtrlAltDel\LKeyReset

\newcommand{\key}[1]{%
  \ifcsdef{LKey#1}
    {\csuse{LKey#1}}
    {\LKey{#1}}%
  }

% for this example only:
\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}
\key{Ctrl}+\key{Shift}+\key{S} \\
\key{ShiftCtrlX}{S} \\
\key{CtrlAltX}{S}

\key{Enter} \key{Alt} \key{F}{12} \key{Esc} \key{Del} \key{Ins} \key{Back} \key{Tab} \\
\key{arrowleft} \key{comma} \key{Win} \key{Menu} \key{AltF}{8} \key{Reset}

\key{L}\key{i}\key{n}\key{u}\key{x}\key{Space}%
\key{B}\key{i}\key{o}\key{l}\key{i}\key{n}\key{u}\key{m}\key{Space}%
\key{K}\key{e}\key{y}\key{b}\key{o}\key{a}\key{r}\key{d}\key{Space}\key{O}
\end{document}
```

[image]