# Typesetting <Esc> key

Tags: typography

I am trying to typeset the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key. I tried 
`\frame{Esc}`   and `$\boxed{\mathrm{Esc}}$` and I get [image]

They don't look beautiful. How else can I typeset the Esc key?

Comment: have a look [here.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5226/keyboard-font-for-latex)

Comment: How to convert menukeys.dtx to menukeys.sty? Please help me.

Comment: Ohhh. I didn't see Nils L's comment when I wrote the answer...

Comment: @minthao_2011 You don’t need to do that manually, just install `menukeys` with the package manager of your TeX distribution.

Answer (score 6):

Using the [`keystroke`](http://ctan.org/pkg/keystroke) package seems to be the way forward.

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{keystroke}

\begin{document}
\Esc
\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]