# How to show keys (ctrl, alt, ..., etc.) as fancy as StackOverflow?

Tags: macros, symbols, boxes

In StackOverflow, I can show keys like this: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd>.

How to do the same things in LaTeX?

Comment: I don't think this qualifies for a latex3 tag…

Comment: Related: [Keyboard Font for LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5226/1952)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use the [`menukeys`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/menukeys) package. They look even fancier than in SO...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[os=win]{menukeys}

\begin{document}
\keys{\ctrl + \Alt}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you add the line

```
\renewmenumacro{\keys}[+]{shadowedroundedkeys}
```

in the preamble, you can get even fancier output (with shadows)

[image]