# How to make menukeys support both of win and mac?

Tags: packages, package-options, menukeys

`menukeys` is a very fancy package.

We can use it by:

```
\usepackage[os=win]{menukeys} % Show keys in Windows style
```

or by:

```
\usepackage[os=mac]{menukeys} % Show keys in Mac style
```

However, in my article, I want to show keys in both styles.

How to dynamically switch the style in the same article?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may define two macros to switch the OS style:

```
\makeatletter
\def\setmenukeyswin{\def\tw@mk@os{win}}
\def\setmenukeysmac{\def\tw@mk@os{mac}}
\makeatother
```

Example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{menukeys}
\makeatletter
\def\setmenukeyswin{\def\tw@mk@os{win}}
\def\setmenukeysmac{\def\tw@mk@os{mac}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\setmenukeyswin

\shift \capslock \tab \esc \ctrl \Alt \AltGr \cmd \return \winmenu
\enter \backspace \del \arrowkeyup \arrowkeydown \arrowkeyleft
\arrowkeyright \Space \SPACE

\setmenukeysmac

\shift \capslock \tab \esc \ctrl \Alt \AltGr \cmd \return \enter
\backspace \del \arrowkeyup \arrowkeydown \arrowkeyleft \arrowkeyright
\Space \SPACE

\end{document}
```

**Edit:**

To change the `mackeys` option dynamically, you may define the following macros (*not tested*):

```
\makeatletter
\def\setmackeystext{\def\tw@mk@mackeys{text}}
\def\setmackeyssymbol{\def\tw@mk@mackeys{symbol}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: It might also be of interest that one can append `mac` or `win` to any key macro, e.g., `\ctrlwin` vs. `\ctrlmac` instead of just `\ctrl`. I use this in tables where I contrast key bindings for different operating systems in different columns.

Comment: @FlorianH. You can define your own macros. Ex: `\def\ctrlwin{\setmenukeyswin\ctrl}`

Comment: @Paul Gaborit: Wait, I'm saying that `\ctrlwin` and \ctrlmac` macros *are already defined* in the `menukeys` package (and might be useful in a situation like the OP describes).