# How to add a downloadable .zip link to Overleaf using documentclass Report?

Tags: hyperref, overleaf

.zip have to be added to a chapter:

```
\begin{document}

.....

\chapter{Datasheet}\label{ch:attachment_B}{

\href{file.zip}{Click t download}.


}


\end{document}
```

packages used at the top:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4]{report}

\usepackage{pythonhighlight}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs,makecell,xltabular}
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\usepackage[os=mac]{menukeys}
\renewmenumacro{\keys}[+]{shadowedroundedkeys}
\renewmenumacro{\menu}[>]{angularmenus}
\xpatchcmd*{\SPACE}{2em}{1em}{}{}

\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\arrayrulecolor{gray!60!white}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{{\centering\sffamily{\LARGE\bfseries\@title}\par\vskip\baselineskip{\large\@date}\par}\vskip\baselineskip}
% nifty commands by Paul Gaborit from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/236891/226
\def\setmenukeyswin{\def\tw@mk@os{win}}
\def\setmenukeysmac{\def\tw@mk@os{mac}}
\makeatother


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%5

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{cmss}    
\usepackage{verbatim,amsmath}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,fancyvrb}
\usepackage{graphicx,color,boxedminipage}
\usepackage{ragged2e,colortbl,appendix}
\usepackage{here,multirow,pdfpages}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{dirtree}
\usepackage{placeins}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum,todonotes}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to TeX SE!
I would recommend uploading your `*.zip` file to a cloud storage somewhere (e.g. [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/), [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/), etc.) and then hyperlink it using `\href`, i.e.,

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4]{report}
\usepackage{pythonhighlight}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs,makecell,xltabular}
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\usepackage[os=mac]{menukeys}
\renewmenumacro{\keys}[+]{shadowedroundedkeys}
\renewmenumacro{\menu}[>]{angularmenus}
\xpatchcmd*{\SPACE}{2em}{1em}{}{}

\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\arrayrulecolor{gray!60!white}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{{\centering\sffamily{\LARGE\bfseries\@title}\par\vskip\baselineskip{\large\@date}\par}\vskip\baselineskip}
% nifty commands by Paul Gaborit from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/236891/226
\def\setmenukeyswin{\def\tw@mk@os{win}}
\def\setmenukeysmac{\def\tw@mk@os{mac}}
\makeatother


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%5

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{cmss}    
\usepackage{verbatim,amsmath}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,fancyvrb}
\usepackage{graphicx,color,boxedminipage}
\usepackage{ragged2e,colortbl,appendix}
\usepackage{here,multirow,pdfpages}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{dirtree}
\usepackage{placeins}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum,todonotes}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Datasheet}\label{ch:attachment_B}{

\href{<download link from a cloud storage>}{(Click to download)}.


}
\end{document}
```

If I understand correctly, what you want to do is actually make a hyperlink to download a `*.zip` file from what you uploaded on an [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/) project. The issue is that an Overleaf project (which includes the `*.zip` file download link) is private until you decide to allow other users to view/edit it either via email or by turning on link-sharing.

The solution I would suggest is for you to also upload the `*.zip` file on a cloud storage somewhere else

or

turn on the Overleaf project's link-sharing (view only) and then use the link inside a `\href` so that the viewer can manually navigate and download the corresponding `*.zip` file. Hope this helps.